# Changing Value of the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i have the following Object, basically it is a state in react app. So what i want to acheive is that make a function that can change the value of the keys depending upon what is passed in the function and then update the state.In the function i can send multiple keys to change its value, currently sending showProduct but can send isEditable aswell.Also i need to change the id in the strings.

```
let obj = { id: "",
    isEditable: false,
    showProduct: false,
    shipment: false,
    create_shipment: false}
```

This is what i have tried, like checking if the name is equal to key and then manipulate it.Is this the correct way?

```
const handler = (name,id) => {
  const prevState = {...obj}
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(prevState)) {
  if(key === name) {
    key = !value
  }
}
setState(prevState)
}

handler('showProduct',id)
```

Comment: Not really. Also, where do you use the passed `id` argument? Was that supposed to replace the `id` property of the object?

Comment: You are asking about "the correct way", which can be broad to answer. The code you posted can do it's job but is it the best way to handle state? [React has it's own state functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic keys to identify a specific property you want to update.

```
const handler = (name, id) => {
  setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState, // shallow copy state
    id: id ?? prevState.id, // updates id if not null/undefined
    [name]: !prevState[name], // toggle property by dynamic key
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make single function to change values of your object then you need to pass two arguments. First `key` and second `value` that you want to change.

So you need to change your function like below:-

```
  const handler = (key, value) => {
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [key]: value
    }));
  };

  handler("showProduct", true)
  handler("id", "newId")
```

Comment: updated, thanks @TJ

Answer (score 0):

you should not useSetstate for object state value. Btw you can use useReducer

```
const initState = { 
    id: "",
    isEditable: false,
    showProduct: false,
    shipment: false,
    create_shipment: false
}

const objReducer = (state, action) =; {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "MODIFY_OBJECT":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.key]: [action.payload.value]      
};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};


const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(objReducer, initState);
```

then you can modify object by dispatch an action like this:

```
dispatch({ type: "MODIFY_OBJECT", payload:{key: 'id', value: 'newId'}});
```

Comment: The `useState` hook is acceptable. If state was more complex and had nested properties then I'd be inclined to agree that `usereducer` might then be a better option. Also, unless there is new syntax, there are issues in your snippet, `dispatch` consumes a single argument, and there's no `payload` property on the action object so your reducer logic will throw error.